# How to find out what is being accesed in Apache logs

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, cpu-usage

I am managing a dedicated server with hundreds of websites, in which there is a main log for Apache.

The server has spikes in Apache CPU usage once every 4 or 5 hours and after a review I found in Apache access_logs lines like this:

```
128.223.8.111 - [15/Jul/2015:02:36:09 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 159855ms 400 - "-" "-"
160.36.57.172 - [15/Jul/2015:02:57:21 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 105350ms 400 - "-" "-"
142.103.2.2 - [15/Jul/2015:03:45:29 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 130384ms 400 - "-" "-"
```

Which correspond to these ones in the error_logs

```
[Wed Jul 15 02:36:09 2015] [error] [client 128.223.8.111] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /
[Wed Jul 15 02:57:21 2015] [error] [client 160.36.57.172] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /
[Wed Jul 15 03:45:29 2015] [error] [client 142.103.2.2] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /
```

Now I want to track them down and find how are they happening.
From the error log I understand that someone is trying to access the server without selecting a hostname, however I don't understand how is that possible.

On the same line 105~159 seconds is a lot, but I am not sure what do those represent, because it is not accessing any php file so it isn't execution time, so how can I limit those.

Any tips on how to find the cause will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, someone accesses `http://ip.add.re.ss`. That retrieves a page without hostname.

You can make a default virtual host in Apache that returns 404 to the visitor to minimize the effect of these requests.

Comment: How can I make the virtual host so it doesn't interfere with the ones created by the control panel(Parallel Plesk)